# Map reduce Driver Code not Working

Tags: java, mapreduce, bigdata

I am learning Big Data Hadoop by my own and I wrote a Simple Map Reduce code for 
 Word Count Which is not working .Please lets have a look

```
// importing all classes

public class WordCount {

public static class Map extends
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String Line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(Line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            value.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
            context.write(value, new IntWritable(1));
        }
    }
}

public static class Reduce extends
        Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
            Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable x : values) {
            sum = sum + x.get();
        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = new Job(conf, "Word Count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

}

}
```

But after replacing these lines

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
```

in driver code from these

```
    Path outputPath = new Path(args[1]);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    outputPath.getFileSystem(conf).delete(outputPath);

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

then it works properly.

May I know the reason and what these lines are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that when you say it is not working, so you would be getting below error :-

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: **Output directory hdfs://localhost:54310/<<your_output_directory>> already exists**
```

The output directory should not exists before the map reduce job is submitted. So it might have given you the above exception.

The new lines of code that you used in driver, gets the FileSystem (either local/hdfs based on conf object) from path and deletes the output path before the map reduce job is submitted. So now the job executes as the output directory doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks man.. it works if I delete the output directory manually before running code.

Comment: What is the last line means .This line does                  System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);             
Is it neccesary to have this line because without this line my program isn't even executing nor it showing any error.

Comment: It starts the execution of the map reduce job and waits for its completion. When the job execution is done it returns the code to System.exit which will exit your Java program. Yes it is necessary to have this line.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell me what error you are getting earlier.
may this error is related to output path is already exist.
here you have written code that will delete output path every time.
If output path already exist then it will delete that path.
you can write this code like that .

```
Path outputPath = new Path(args[1]);
if (outputPath.getFileSystem(conf).exist()) {
outputPath.getFileSystem(conf).delete(outputPath);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am getting Path already exists but When I make the new Directory and Passing it as output directory even than I am getting same error.